# How can I have multiple HtmlHelperExtensions in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created one file and added a HtmlHelperExtensions class.

```
  public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {

        private const string Nbsp = "&nbsp;";
        private const string SelAttribute = " selected='selected'";

        public static MvcHtmlString NbspIfEmpty(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
        {
            var str = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? Nbsp : value;
            return new MvcHtmlString(str);
        }

        etc...
```

Now I would like to add more files with more HtmlHelperExtensions. However when I do this I get an error saying:

```
Duplicate definition: HtmlHelperExtensions
```

Is it possible for me to have more than one of these classes?

Answer (score 2):

Just name the class something different. You're not allowed duplicate type names under one namespace.

Here's a good tutorial on creating custom Html helpers: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs.

Answer (score 1):

You could name the class differently as stated by @Andrew Whitaker or you could use the [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword.

```
public static partial class HtmlHelperExtensions 
{
    // helpers ...
}

public static partial class HtmlHelperExtensions 
{
    // other helpers ...
}
```